# Bayesian network error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, bayesian, backpropagation

I tried to run my following code to train my Bayesian network.

```
p = [-1:.05:1];
t = sin(2*pi*p)+0.1*randn(size(p));
net = feedforwardnet(2,'trainbr');
net = train(net,p,t);
a = net(p);
```

and received an error which is as below;

```
Default value is not a member of type "nntype.training_fcn".
Error using nnetParamInfo (line 28)
FCN does not return an info object.

Error in feedforwardnet>get_info (line 87)
    nnetParamInfo('trainFcn','Training 
Function','nntype.training_fcn','trainlm',...

Error in feedforwardnet (line 39)
  if isempty(INFO), INFO = get_info; end

Error in backpropag_no_noise (line 29)
net1=feedforwardnet(20,'trainbr');
```

I used the same example as given in the MATLAB documentation. It works sometimes with the same code and it throws me an error simply for most of the times. I passed the network and argument as suggested in the documentation. Any help.

Comment: what is your Matlab's version? I check your code and it works correctly!

Comment: I use version 2017a. Yes that's what, if I put the same code in online matlab version, it works. I am puzzled and already last 2 days solving this.

Comment: I already hear from people that v 2017 changed a lot, maybe it is just a bug in new version! try old version scripts, and see if it helps, I don't have 2017 version to check, sorry

Answer (score 0):

your code works on my Matlab,
try to define network training function separately by following code, maybe it works. Also put number of network layer's neurons in the bracket.

`net = feedforwardnet([2],'trainbr');
net = train(net,p,t);
net.trainFcn='trainbr';`

Comment: I am sorry it does not work and throws me the same error. The error message is not explanatory and still trying to figure out.

Comment: It is weird! Is there anything else in your script rather than above code, they may cause this error. add "clear all" function to clear your work-space,     Did you try other learning  algorithms like 'traingdm' or 'trainlm' ?